# Запуск приложения WPF с параметрами

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется приложение WPF, из которого нужно запустить другое небольшое приложение WPF в виде исполнимого файла (.exe) с параметрами, передаваемыми их главного приложения. Причем при старте второго приложеня происходит проверка, если параметров нет, то стартует еще одно окно, где необходимо их ввести вручную. Делаю так, в файле App:

```
    public string[] Parameters { get; set; }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Parameters = e.Args;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

в главном окне приложения:

```
    public string Medicament { get; set; }
    public float Concentration { get; set; }
    public float SpecGravity { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        var parameters = ((App)Application.Current).Parameters;
        SetParameters(parameters);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        TextBoxMg.Focus();
    }

    private void SetParameters(string[] parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            Medicament = parameters[0];
            if (parameters.Length >= 2)
                SpecGravity = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[1]);
            else
                ShowParametersView();
            if (parameters.Length >= 3)
                Concentration = Convert.ToSingle(parameters[2]);
            else
                ShowParametersView();
        }
        else
            ShowParametersView();
    }

    private void ShowParametersView()
    {
        var parametersView = new ParametersView
        {
            Medicament = Medicament,
            SpecGravity = SpecGravity,
            Concentration = Concentration
        };

        parametersView.ShowDialog();
        Medicament = parametersView.Medicament;
        SpecGravity = parametersView.SpecGravity;
        Concentration = parametersView.Concentration;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что второе приложение стартует и тут же закрывается. Насколько смог определить, происходит это из-за установки параметров. Если в конструкторе вместо вызова метода `SetParameters()` вызвать сразу `ShowParametersView()`, то все прекрасно работает.

Что делаю неправильно?

P.S. Из консольного приложения запускается без проблем, под отладчиком с параметрами тоже работает

Comment: Ну мало ли что, может, исключение выбрасывается. Попробуйте запустить второе приложение не из первого, а из-под отладчика и дать ему такие же параметры командной строки.

Comment: Забыл написать. Пробовал конечно же разные варианты. Из под отладчика запускается без проблем, из консольного приложения тоже без проблем.

Comment: Окей, это интереснее. Тогда возможно вы неправильно передаёте параметры. Попробуйте при старте второго приложения скинуть параметры в текстовый файл, по одной штуке на строку.

Comment: Это нужно сделать в App.cs?

Comment: Ну, где угодно. Лучше всего, наверное, в App.cs, да.

Comment: Но до base.OnStartup.

Comment: Сделал, результат тот же

Comment: Отлично, а что в файле?

Comment: В файле все нормально. Уже попробовал заменить в SetParameters свойства на переменные, результат тот же. Какая-то проблема, по-моему с этим присвоением.

Comment: Нашел источник ошибки. В SetParameters() я конвертирую второй и третий параметры в float. Стоило только убрать эту конвертацию и все заработало. Т.е. нужно теперь "ловить" параметры, записывать в строки, а конвертировать только при необходимости

Comment: @VladD Огромное спасибо за помощь. Ошибка была моя. Все дело в способе передачи параметров из одного приложения в другое. Параметры передаются в виде строки. При получения этой строки C# автоматически конвертирует ее в массив так, что каждое отдельное слово - это элемент массива. При тестировании я передавал первый параметер одним словом. В реальном приложении первый параметер - это название медикамента. Это название состоит не из одного слова, а из нескольких, поэтому происходила проблема с конвертацией второго и третьего параметра. Substring решил все проблемы.

Comment: Если в параметре есть пробелы, то его надо заключать в "кавычки", чтобы аргументы приходили как надо.

Comment: @S_Schmal: вот и хорошо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы параметры получаете до инициализации в главном окне

> public MainWindow()
> {
> var parameters = ((App)Application.Current).Parameters;
> SetParameters(parameters);
> InitializeComponent();
> DataContext = this;
> TextBoxMg.Focus();
> }

Я бы попробовал получить список параметров после инициализации:

1. InitializeComponent();
2. var parameters = ((App)Application.Current).Parameters;
3. SetParameters(parameters);